# Form is being not created in Django and yet no errors are returned

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a profile update page for applicant, but the profile html page is only displaying username and email and not other attributes, plus the all the forms I'm creating are not showing in the html page on debugging but the system is not showing any existence of any errors. what could be the problem

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def applicant(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        a_form = ApplicantUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                    request.FILES,
                                    instance=request.user.applicant)
        if u_form.is_valid() and a_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            a_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('account')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        a_form = ApplicantUpdateForm(instance=request.user.applicant)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'a_form': a_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/account_settings.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class ApplicantUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Applicant
        fields = ['mobilephone', 'maddress', 'country', 'homecity', 'citizenship', 'denomination', 'anyspouse',
```

**profile model**

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobilephone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    maddress = models.TextField()
    homecity = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    citizenship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    denomination = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    anyspouse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='media')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Applicant'
```

[Here is how the page appears, that's the only thing i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Wqa.jpg)

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
# from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='bugema-home'),
    # path('form/', views.applicant_form, name="applicant_form"),
    path('list/', views.applicant_list, name="applicant_list"),
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('account/', views.accountSettings, name="account"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**account_settings.html**

```
{%  extends 'applyBugema/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.applicant.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
      <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.first_name }}</p>
      <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.last_name }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.mobilephone }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.maddress }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.homecity }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.citizenship }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.country }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.denomination }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ applicant.anyspouse }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- FORM HERE -->
      <div class="content-section">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
            <p>Edit Details</p>
          </legend>
          <form method="POST" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ u_form|crispy }}
          {{ a_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Continue to Apply...</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: What does your `urls.py` file look like?

Comment: Can you also paste the content of your template ?

Comment: I have edited them in the question

Comment: I feel, you don't have any data present in your DB. Can you try running below commands and see what data exists in your Applicant model.

    `python manage.py shell`
    `from .models import Applicant`
    `Applicant.objects.all()`